# Expiry of url after file upload using Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been researching and I haven't found the maximum time limit that a url can be accessed after file upload using Azure Blob Storage. The url that will be generated will be accessed by anonymous users and I wanted to know what is the maximum time that anonymous users can access it?

Comment: If you're using sas token, you specify the max time limit by yourself.

Comment: What kind of URL are we talking about? Because for URLs with a SAS token it depends on the validity of the SAS token, while if we're talking about a public container, it will be accessible through this URL for the duration of the Blob's lifetime.

Comment: @rickvdbosch yes, URL with a SAS token. Can I specify the validity of the SAS token? can I set it's validity, for example, years from now?

Comment: @IvanYang no maximum time limit when i set it? for example i will set the limit to 5 years from now is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. SAS URL accepts a parameter which defines when that SAS URL will expire. It can be any date in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The url that will be generated will be accessed by anonymous users and
>   I wanted to know what is the maximum time that anonymous users can
>   access it?

As such there's no maximum time limit imposed by Azure on the expiry of a SAS URL. You can set it to `9999-12-31T23:59:59Z` so that it never expires.

However it is not recommended. You should always issue SAS URLs that are short lived so that they can't be misused.

You can find more information about the best practices for SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas.

Comment: Hi Mantri, do you know is there any reference about maximum time for expiry time? I remembered I saw it before, but cannot find it now.

Comment: I could not find any restrictions regarding this.